# У меня есть div карточка, которая содержать картинку (не фон), h2, и ещё пару строчек информации. Как сделать чтобы картинка выходила за фон div-a?

Tags: html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]что то похожее на то что на этом фото.

Comment: а зачем ей выходить за фон дива?

Comment: на фото она выходит за фон дива насколько я понимаю, или нет?

Comment: нет. смотря про какой див ты говоришь

Answer (score 0):

```css
        .wrapper {
        margin:50px;
            background: blue;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .card {
            width: 150px;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            height: 140px;
            background: aqua;
        }
        img {
            height: 200px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 115px;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="card">
            <img
                src="https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/541-5413340_transparent-character-traits-clipart-joy-inside-out-png.png" />
            <h2>Sadness</h2>
            <span>Movie inside Out</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое!